# vbscript AD Email signature ReplyMessageSignature

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to get this code working;

```
{meat snipped}
Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature
Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries
Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()
objSignatureEntries.Add "Reply Signature 003", objSelection
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Reply Signature 003"
objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit
```

but during login I get an Unspecified error on this line;
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Reply Signature 003"

If I run the code without that line, it works perfectly. But it only adds the signature to the signature list. I want to add it so that it's automatically applied for new (not included above) and reply emails. This means the user has to manually select the sig.

I've googled and googled. I've seen the above code working in no less than 30 different scripts. No idea why it's not working for me. Starting to wonder if it's a coding issue or an AD policy issue...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Omitted [`NewMessageSignature` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.emailsignature.newmessagesignature(v=office.14).aspx) setting (the signature that Microsoft Word appends to new e-mail messages *should* be set). Try next:

```
'''
Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()
objSignatureEntries.Add "Reply Signature 003", objSelection
objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Reply Signature 003" 
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Reply Signature 003"
objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit
```

Comment: Sorry, same error. (As I said, I deliberately left NewMessageSignature out).

Comment: Sorry, no mention of `NewMessageSignature` in your original question. Update it, please.  Then I will delete my answer...